# Adding column to existing csv output from vcenter powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, powercli

location    vcenter     username    password
abc         10.1        X           xxx
def         10.2        Y           yyy

a csv file which has location column which is a location and in that location IP column indicates the vCenter IP

i need to generate all host details and add location field as the first field in the final csv but not able to do so

Example

Suppose location abc has a vCenter with 5 hosts and location def has a vCenter with 3 hosts

The output should look like

```
location    name    version
abc         h1      6.5
abc         h2      6.5
abc         h3      6.5
abc         h4      6.5
abc         h5      6.5 
def         hxx     6.7
def         hyy     6.7
def         hzz     6.7
```

script

```
$inventory = Import-Csv -path path.csv

foreach($i in $inventory){
    Connect-VIServer -Server $i.vcenter -User $i.username -Password $i.password
    Get-VMHost | Select-Object -Property Name,Version | Export-csv tempoutput.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
    $ExistingCSV = Import-Csv -Path 'tempoutput.csv'
    $ExistingCSV | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Location' -Value $i.location 
    $ExistingCSV | Export-Csv final.csv -NoTypeInformation  
    Disconnect-VIServer -Server $i.vcenter -Force -Confirm:$false
}
```

But this is not working

Comment: Location is getting printed but it is overwriting the earlier one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only write to the output CSV once provided your memory can hold all of the `Get-VMHost` data. You may make use of calculated properties to prevent having to use a temporary CSV file.

```
$inventory = Import-Csv -path path.csv

$output = foreach ($i in $inventory) {
    $null = Connect-VIServer -Server $i.vcenter -User $i.username -Password $i.password
    Get-VMHost | Select-Object -Property Name,Version,@{n='Location';e={$i.Location}}
    $null = Disconnect-VIServer -Server $i.vcenter -Force -Confirm:$false
}

$output | Export-Csv final.csv -NoType
```

---

It may be worthwhile to consider a redesign ***if you have repeated entries of the same vCenter and credentials in the CSV file***. Connecting and disconnecting to the same vCenter so many times is likely inefficient. You may make use of `Group-Object` to only connect and disconnect from vCenter when the vCenter server changes.

```
$inventory = Import-Csv -path path.csv | Group-Object vcenter,username,password | Foreach-Object {
    $vc = $_.Group[0] | Select-Object vcenter,username,password,location
    $null = Connect-VIServer -Server $vc.vcenter -User $vc.username -Password $vc.password
    Get-VMHost | Select-Object -Property Name,Version,@{n='Location';e={$vc.Location}}
    $null = Disconnect-VIServer -Server $vc.vcenter -Force -Confirm:$false
}

$inventory | Export-Csv final.csv -NoType
```

---

In your attempt, you are reading the entire temp CSV in `$ExistingCSV` during each loop iteration. Then you are adding the property `Location` to the entire object `$ExistingCSV`, which adds it to every item in the `$ExistingCSV` list with the same value. So at the end of the loop, every line of the CSV has a `Location` value that matches the last item in the loop.

Comment: Works great.. Can u tell me my mistake as I am not abel to figure out

Comment: @DishantDhokia I added it to my post.